# Build failure while executing flutter build apk on cmd

Tags: flutter

I am getting the following build failure which absolutely unrelated to the code I have written. it is entirely flutterish error. Can someone tell me how to resolve these errors:

> ```
>     ^^^^^^^^^^^^
> ```
>
> file:///C:/Users//Documents/FLUTTER/flutter_windows_v1.0.0-stable/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/animated_icons/data/view_list.g.dart:2601:9: Error: Method not found: '_PathCubicTo'.
>           _PathCubicTo(
>           ^^^^^^^^^^^^
>   file:///C:/Users//Documents/FLUTTER/flutter_windows_v1.0.0-stable/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/animated_icons/data/view_list.g.dart:2675:9: Error: Method not found: '_PathCubicTo'.
>           _PathCubicTo(
>           ^^^^^^^^^^^^
>   file:///C:/Users//Documents/FLUTTER/flutter_windows_v1.0.0-stable/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/animated_icons/data/view_list.g.dart:2749:9: Error: Method not found: '_PathCubicTo'.
>           _PathCubicTo(
>           ^^^^^^^^^^^^
>   file:///C:/Users//Documents/FLUTTER/flutter_windows_v1.0.0-stable/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/animated_icons/data/view_list.g.dart:2823:9: Error: Method not found: '_PathClose'.
>           _PathClose(
>           ^^^^^^^^^^
>   file:///C:/Users//Documents/FLUTTER/flutter_windows_v1.0.0-stable/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/animated_icons/data/view_list.g.dart:2500:18: Error: '_PathCommand' isn't a type.
>         commands: <_PathCommand>[
>                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^
>   file:///C:/Users//Documents/FLUTTER/flutter_windows_v1.0.0-stable/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/animated_icons/data/view_list.g.dart:2475:5: Error: Method not found: '_PathFrames'.
>       _PathFrames(
>       ^^^^^^^^^^^
>   file:///C:/Users//Documents/FLUTTER/flutter_windows_v1.0.0-stable/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/animated_icons/data/view_list.g.dart:2853:9: Error: Method not found: '_PathMoveTo'.
>           _PathMoveTo(
>           ^^^^^^^^^^^
>   file:///C:/Users//Documents/FLUTTER/flutter_windows_v1.0.0-stable/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/animated_icons/data/view_list.g.dart:2879:9: Error: Method not found: '_PathCubicTo'.
>           _PathCubicTo(
>           ^^^^^^^^^^^^
>   file:///C:/Users//Documents/FLUTTER/flutter_windows_v1.0.0-stable/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/animated_icons/data/view_list.g.dart:2953:9: Error: Method not found: '_PathCubicTo'.
>           _PathCubicTo(
>           ^^^^^^^^^^^^
>   file:///C:/Users//Documents/FLUTTER/flutter_windows_v1.0.0-stable/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/animated_icons/data/view_list.g.dart:3027:9: Error: Method not found: '_PathCubicTo'.
>           _PathCubicTo(
>           ^^^^^^^^^^^^
>   file:///C:/Users//Documents/FLUTTER/flutter_windows_v1.0.0-stable/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/animated_icons/data/view_list.g.dart:3101:9: Error: Method not found: '_PathCubicTo'.
>           _PathCubicTo(
>           ^^^^^^^^^^^^
>   file:///C:/Users//Documents/FLUTTER/flutter_windows_v1.0.0-stable/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/animated_icons/data/view_list.g.dart:3175:9: Error: Method not found: '_PathClose'.
>           _PathClose(
>           ^^^^^^^^^^
>   file:///C:/Users//Documents/FLUTTER/flutter_windows_v1.0.0-stable/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/animated_icons/data/view_list.g.dart:2852:18: Error: '_PathCommand' isn't a type.
>         commands: <_PathCommand>[
>                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^
>   file:///C:/Users//Documents/FLUTTER/flutter_windows_v1.0.0-stable/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/animated_icons/data/view_list.g.dart:2827:5: Error: Method not found: '_PathFrames'.
>       _PathFrames(
>       ^^^^^^^^^^^
>   file:///C:/Users//Documents/FLUTTER/flutter_windows_v1.0.0-stable/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/animated_icons/data/view_list.g.dart:3205:9: Error: Method not found: '_PathMoveTo'.
>           _PathMoveTo(
>           ^^^^^^^^^^^
>   file:///C:/Users//Documents/FLUTTER/flutter_windows_v1.0.0-stable/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/animated_icons/data/view_list.g.dart:3231:9: Error: Method not found: '_PathCubicTo'.
>           _PathCubicTo(
>           ^^^^^^^^^^^^
>   file:///C:/Users//Documents/FLUTTER/flutter_windows_v1.0.0-stable/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/animated_icons/data/view_list.g.dart:3305:9: Error: Method not found: '_PathCubicTo'.
>           _PathCubicTo(
>           ^^^^^^^^^^^^
>   file:///C:/Users//Documents/FLUTTER/flutter_windows_v1.0.0-stable/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/animated_icons/data/view_list.g.dart:3379:9: Error: Method not found: '_PathCubicTo'.
>           _PathCubicTo(
>           ^^^^^^^^^^^^
>   file:///C:/Users//Documents/FLUTTER/flutter_windows_v1.0.0-stable/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/animated_icons/data/view_list.g.dart:3453:9: Error: Method not found: '_PathCubicTo'.
>           _PathCubicTo(
>           ^^^^^^^^^^^^
>   file:///C:/Users//Documents/FLUTTER/flutter_windows_v1.0.0-stable/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/animated_icons/data/view_list.g.dart:3527:9: Error: Method not found: '_PathClose'.
>           _PathClose(
>           ^^^^^^^^^^
>   file:///C:/Users//Documents/FLUTTER/flutter_windows_v1.0.0-stable/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/animated_icons/data/view_list.g.dart:3204:18: Error: '_PathCommand' isn't a type.
>         commands: <_PathCommand>[
>                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^
>   file:///C:/Users//Documents/FLUTTER/flutter_windows_v1.0.0-stable/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/animated_icons/data/view_list.g.dart:3179:5: Error: Method not found: '_PathFrames'.
>       _PathFrames(
>       ^^^^^^^^^^^
>   file:///C:/Users//Documents/FLUTTER/flutter_windows_v1.0.0-stable/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/animated_icons/data/view_list.g.dart:3557:9: Error: Method not found: '_PathMoveTo'.
>           _PathMoveTo(
>           ^^^^^^^^^^^
>   file:///C:/Users//Documents/FLUTTER/flutter_windows_v1.0.0-stable/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/animated_icons/data/view_list.g.dart:3583:9: Error: Method not found: '_PathCubicTo'.
>           _PathCubicTo(
>           ^^^^^^^^^^^^
>   file:///C:/Users//Documents/FLUTTER/flutter_windows_v1.0.0-stable/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/animated_icons/data/view_list.g.dart:3657:9: Error: Method not found: '_PathCubicTo'.
>           _PathCubicTo(
>           ^^^^^^^^^^^^
>   file:///C:/Users//Documents/FLUTTER/flutter_windows_v1.0.0-stable/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/animated_icons/data/view_list.g.dart:3731:9: Error: Method not found: '_PathCubicTo'.
>           _PathCubicTo(
>           ^^^^^^^^^^^^
>   file:///C:/Users//Documents/FLUTTER/flutter_windows_v1.0.0-stable/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/animated_icons/data/view_list.g.dart:3805:9: Error: Method not found: '_PathCubicTo'.
>           _PathCubicTo(
>           ^^^^^^^^^^^^
>   file:///C:/Users//Documents/FLUTTER/flutter_windows_v1.0.0-stable/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/animated_icons/data/view_list.g.dart:3879:9: Error: Method not found: '_PathClose'.
>           _PathClose(
>           ^^^^^^^^^^
>   file:///C:/Users//Documents/FLUTTER/flutter_windows_v1.0.0-stable/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/animated_icons/data/view_list.g.dart:3556:18: Error: '_PathCommand' isn't a type.
>         commands: <_PathCommand>[
>                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^
>   file:///C:/Users//Documents/FLUTTER/flutter_windows_v1.0.0-stable/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/animated_icons/data/view_list.g.dart:3531:5: Error: Method not found: '_PathFrames'.
>       _PathFrames(
>       ^^^^^^^^^^^
>   file:///C:/Users//Documents/FLUTTER/flutter_windows_v1.0.0-stable/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/animated_icons/data/view_list.g.dart:3909:9: Error: Method not found: '_PathMoveTo'.
>           _PathMoveTo(
>           ^^^^^^^^^^^
>   file:///C:/Users//Documents/FLUTTER/flutter_windows_v1.0.0-stable/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/animated_icons/data/view_list.g.dart:3935:9: Error: Method not found: '_PathCubicTo'.
>           _PathCubicTo(
>           ^^^^^^^^^^^^
>   file:///C:/Users//Documents/FLUTTER/flutter_windows_v1.0.0-stable/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/animated_icons/data/view_list.g.dart:4009:9: Error: Method not found: '_PathCubicTo'.
>           _PathCubicTo(
>           ^^^^^^^^^^^^
>   file:///C:/Users//Documents/FLUTTER/flutter_windows_v1.0.0-stable/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/animated_icons/data/view_list.g.dart:4083:9: Error: Method not found: '_PathCubicTo'.
>           _PathCubicTo(
>           ^^^^^^^^^^^^
>   file:///C:/Users//Documents/FLUTTER/flutter_windows_v1.0.0-stable/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/animated_icons/data/view_list.g.dart:4157:9: Error: Method not found: '_PathCubicTo'.
>           _PathCubicTo(
>           ^^^^^^^^^^^^
>   file:///C:/Users//Documents/FLUTTER/flutter_windows_v1.0.0-stable/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/animated_icons/data/view_list.g.dart:4231:9: Error: Method not found: '_PathClose'.
>           _PathClose(
>           ^^^^^^^^^^
>   file:///C:/Users//Documents/FLUTTER/flutter_windows_v1.0.0-stable/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/animated_icons/data/view_list.g.dart:3908:18: Error: '_PathCommand' isn't a type.
>         commands: <_PathCommand>[
>                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^
>   file:///C:/Users//Documents/FLUTTER/flutter_windows_v1.0.0-stable/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/animated_icons/data/view_list.g.dart:3883:5: Error: Method not found: '_PathFrames'.
>       _PathFrames(
>       ^^^^^^^^^^^
>   file:///C:/Users//Documents/FLUTTER/flutter_windows_v1.0.0-stable/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/animated_icons/data/view_list.g.dart:10:4: Error: '_PathFrames' isn't a type.
>     <_PathFrames>[
>      ^^^^^^^^^^^
>   file:///C:/Users//Documents/FLUTTER/flutter_windows_v1.0.0-stable/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/arc.dart:164:26: Error: Method not found: 'lerpDouble'.
>       final double angle = lerpDouble(_beginAngle, _endAngle, t);
>                            ^^^^^^^^^^
>   file:///C:/Users//Documents/FLUTTER/flutter_windows_v1.0.0-stable/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/arc.dart:164:26: Error: The method 'lerpDouble' isn't defined for the class '#lib1::MaterialPointArcTween'.
>   Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'lerpDouble'.
>       final double angle = lerpDouble(_beginAngle, _endAngle, t);
>                            ^^^^^^^^^^
>   file:///C:/Users//Documents/FLUTTER/flutter_windows_v1.0.0-stable/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/arc.dart:406:26: Error: Method not found: 'lerpDouble'.
>       final double width = lerpDouble(begin.width, end.width, t);
>                            ^^^^^^^^^^
>   file:///C:/Users//Documents/FLUTTER/flutter_windows_v1.0.0-stable/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/arc.dart:407:27: Error: Method not found: 'lerpDouble'.
>       final double height = lerpDouble(begin.height, end.height, t);
>                             ^^^^^^^^^^
>   file:///C:/Users//Documents/FLUTTER/flutter_windows_v1.0.0-stable/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/arc.dart:406:26: Error: The method 'lerpDouble' isn't defined for the class '#lib1::MaterialRectCenterArcTween'.
>   Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'lerpDouble'.
>       final double width = lerpDouble(begin.width, end.width, t);
>                            ^^^^^^^^^^
>   file:///C:/Users//Documents/FLUTTER/flutter_windows_v1.0.0-stable/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/arc.dart:407:27: Error: The method 'lerpDouble' isn't defined for the class '#lib1::MaterialRectCenterArcTween'.
>   Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'lerpDouble'.
>       final double height = lerpDouble(begin.height, end.height, t);
>                             ^^^^^^^^^^
>   file:///C:/Users//Documents/FLUTTER/flutter_windows_v1.0.0-stable/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/input_border.dart:465:29: Error: Method not found: 'lerpDouble'.
>         final double extent = lerpDouble(0.0, gapExtent + gapPadding * 2.0, gapPercentage);
>                               ^^^^^^^^^^
>   file:///C:/Users//Documents/FLUTTER/flutter_windows_v1.0.0-stable/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/input_border.dart:465:29: Error: The method 'lerpDouble' isn't defined for the class '#lib1::OutlineInputBorder'.
>   Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'lerpDouble'.
>         final double extent = lerpDouble(0.0, gapExtent + gapPadding * 2.0, gapPercentage);
>                               ^^^^^^^^^^
>   Compiler terminated unexpectedly.

Comment: Looks like https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Workarounds-for-common-issues#flutter-installation-corrupted

Comment: Which command should I run on my cmd to fix this issue?